# Generic InternPool<T> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, object-pooling

How would I write a generic `InternPool<T>` in Java? Does it need a `Internable` interface?

`String` in Java has interning capabilities; I want to intern classes like `BigDecimal` and `Account`.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
public class InternPool<T> {

    private WeakHashMap<T, WeakReference<T>> pool = 
        new WeakHashMap<T, WeakReference<T>>();

    public synchronized T intern(T object) {
        T res = null;
        // (The loop is needed to deal with race
        // conditions where the GC runs while we are
        // accessing the 'pool' map or the 'ref' object.)
        do {
            WeakReference<T> ref = pool.get(object);
            if (ref == null) {
                ref = new WeakReference<T>(object);
                pool.put(object, ref);
                res = object;
            } else {
                res = ref.get();
            }
        } while (res == null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

This depends on the pool element class implementing the `equals` and `hashCode` to provide "equality by value" and to obey to the API contracts for those methods.  But `BigDecimal` certainly does.

---

**UPDATE** - for an explanation of why we need a `WeakHashMap<T, WeakReference<T>>` rather than a `WeakHashMap<T, T>`, see the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).  The short version is that the key weak-links in the latter won't be broken by the GC because the corresponding entry references are making the values strongly reachable.

Comment: I assume you don't need to check if ref.get() is null.

Comment: I thought not, but I've realized that there is a race condition with the GC.  If the GC runs immediately after the call to `get`, the `ref` returned might be broken by the time we look at it.  The whole lot needs to be in a loop.  Updated.

Comment: Why do you need a WeakReference for the map value? Aren't you already using WeakhashMap so if there is no strong reference to the object the entry will be removed?

Answer (score 6):

For an example take a look at `Interner` from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).  It does *not* require an `Internable` interface, it just relies on `equals` and `hashCode`.

Answer (score 3):

This more sounds like that you're looking for [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

> *Flyweight* is a software design pattern. A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory use by sharing as much data as possible with other similar objects

Click the link, it contains a Java example.

Comment: +1. I think these are both the same pattern (or maybe a Flyweight is just one application of an Interner) but I prefer "Flyweight" because it is easier to google

Answer (score 3):

I would separate the solution into two classes to have cleaner code and also this way getting rid of loop:

```
public class WeakPool<T> {
    private final WeakHashMap<T, WeakReference<T>> pool = new WeakHashMap<T, WeakReference<T>>();
    public T get(T object) {
        final T res;
        WeakReference<T> ref = pool.get(object);
        if (ref != null) {
            res = ref.get();
        } else {
            res = null;
        }
        return res;
    }
    public void put(T object) {
        pool.put(object, new WeakReference<T>(object));
    }
}
```

and the interning class using the weak pool is very simple:

```
public class InternPool<T> {

    private final WeakPool<T> pool = new WeakPool<T>();

    public synchronized T intern(T object) {
        T res = pool.get(object);
        if (res == null) {
            pool.put(object);
            res = object;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick caveat:

It has not been explicitly mentioned above, but it should be obvious that the objects being interned  *must* be of an **immutable** type.

On a second note:  You don't need to use another weak reference to the object as the value in the map, a reference to a static would suffice if you just rely on the map's keyset for the data.  For example, declare:

```
WeakHashMap<T,Boolean>
```

And insert pairs as:

```
pool.put (object, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Which is a minor saving of a WeakReference instance (if you can't reuse the one used for the key).

...or create a WeakSet class, as @PeterVerhas has done with his WeakPool.

Comment: so with your method how can be retrieved the intern representation of an object? iterating by all the keys and checking for equality???

Comment: if someone is looking for optimizing memory use, the performance are quite better than guava weak interners. https://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/util/CanonicalSet.html.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldnt

"WeakReference ref = pool.get(object);"

instead be

WeakReference ref = pool.intern(object);

??

Comment: Sorry misunderstood, it for my comment